# How does Keras compute its loss function for matrix-valued outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I try to compute the next several video frames given a collection of previous frames, i.e. I have a deep neural network that directly outputs a small video clip of dimension `(samples, frames, m, n, channels)`. I train my neural network using Keras' mean squared error loss function.

Keras' implementation of the mean squared error loss function is

```
K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

The computed loss value will in my case still be a rank 4 tensor (which I checked is indeed true).

As the loss function should be scalar I had imagined this will cause a problem but surprisingly there is no warning issued from Keras and I do get some meaningful results.

Any clue as to how Keras is doing its back-propagation in this case? Is there an internal conversion to a scalar loss function that Keras is doing that I am not aware of?

Thank you!